# what would be a good db design for database base email system?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a simple table like this in mind to create a db base email system,
is this the best approach ?

```
TABLE `message`
      - id
      - parent_id
      - message
      - subject
      - created_on
      - is_draft
      - sender_profile_id      


TABLE `email_message`
      - id
      - is_read
      - is_deleted
      - message_id
      - profile_id
```

case 1: profile A sending email to profile B,
   and B Replies back (one to one
   communication)

```
INSERT INTO `message` (`id`, `parent_id`, `message`, `subject`, `created_on`, `is_draft`, `sender_profile_id`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Hi what''s up how are u', 'Hi', '2010-12-08 11:27:54', 0, 1),
(2, 1, 'yeah i am gud', 0, '2010-12-08 11:28:19', 0, 2);

INSERT INTO `email_message` (`id`, `is_read`, `is_deleted`, `message_id`, `profile_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 0, 2, 1);
```

case 2:

-Profile A sending email to profile B,C, D.

-Profile B repling back all to whole group.

-A replying again to whole group.

-C replies to A only

```
INSERT INTO `message` (`id`, `parent_id`, `message`, `subject`, `created_on`, `is_draft`, `receiver_profile_id`) VALUES
(3, 0, 'Hi what''s up how are u', 'Hi', '2010-12-08 11:27:54', 0, 1),
(4, 3, 'yeah i am gud.', 0, '2010-12-08 11:28:19', 0, 2),
(5, 3, 'why are u gud?', 0, '2010-12-08 11:28:19', 0, 1),
(6, 3, 'what?', 0, '2010-12-08 11:28:19', 0, 3);

INSERT INTO `email_message` (`id`, `is_read`, `is_deleted`, `message_id`, `profile_id`) VALUES
(3, 1, 0, 3, 2),
(4, 0, 0, 3, 3),
(5, 0, 0, 3, 4),        

(6, 0, 0, 4, 1),
(7, 0, 0, 4, 3),
(8, 0, 0, 4, 4),

(3, 0, 0, 5, 2),
(4, 0, 0, 5, 3),
(5, 0, 0, 5, 4),

(6, 0, 0, 6, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a single table would be a lot easier to impliment :

TABLE Message
    - MessageId (GUID)
    - ParentId (GUID)
    - Subject
    - Message
    - To
    - Sender
    - CreatedOn
    - isDraft
    - isDeleted
    - isRead

If you are sending an email to a group, just create multiple records with different "To" entries

Comment: also, I assume you want some deleted items folder? (hence the reason for the isDeleted flag, otherwise, just delete the record and be done). If you are doing that, you might want to consider the policy for when the folder gets deleted - if it's something like "messaged deleted more than 5 days ago" then you need to keep track of the deleted date. But I think you could probably go with something like "messages older than 30 days" in which case the createdOn date will suffice.

Comment: hummm create multiple records with different To, but won't this create redundant message data ?

Comment: Yes, but it would make your implementation a lot cleaner, one record = one message. You could do it your way, in which case your proposed schema seems to fit the bill

Comment: From my point of view , we need atleast two tables , through that we can handle entire internal mail system module , and we can separate those records without any redundant data.